# javascript iframe: accessing http from https

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, amazon-s3

I have a page that has an iframe which loads html template from amazon aws s3 bucket. In the iframe, I want to take the link of the parent window, then add some parameters.

E.g: My parent window has the link http://xx.xx.x.xxx:8088 . I want to take this url, apprend "#abc/edf" and redirect to that page. But I cannot because my iFrame has url https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com

The error I get is

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://xx.xx.x.xxx:8088".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

The javascript I used to redirect to another page from within an iFrame

```
function navigateTo(e){
    var destination = e.data.destination;
    var url = window.parent.location.host;

    window.parent.location.href = url+destination;
}

$("#button").click({destination: "/#abc/edf"}, navigateTo);
```

html

```
<div id="button"><a href="#">Redirect to another page</a></div>
```

I cannot use absolute path for a reason. The parent window link will change somehow. I think the best solution is to take the parent url and append the parameters that I want. How can I make this happen without getting the security error?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "you can't."

Browser security model precludes cross-domain and cross-protocol scripting from the client side. Your embedded iframe under the https protocol is not allowed to access (not even read) its parent's non-https context.

To do what you want, both contexts must agree on both domain of origin and protocol in order to interact on the client side.